# 雑誌の通りにコードしたのですがNameError: name 'PClass' is not definedと出てしまった

Tags: python, python3, 機械学習, kaggle

機械学習の雑誌からpythonを始めた超初心者でKaggleのタイタニック号生存者予想をやっているのですが、雑誌の通りにコードしたのですが後半のグラフを作るときのコードがNameError: name 'PClass' is not definedと出てしまい、行き詰ってしまいました・・・

どなたか解決策をお願いします...
ちなみに、雑誌は日経ソフトウェアの「タイタニックでデータ分析の特集」で、使ってるのは雑誌に沿ってやっているのでGoogle Clabを使用しています。
あと、ついでにここの質問サイトも初心者なので気になる点があればご教授お願いします。

```
from google.colab import files
upload = files.upload()

from google.colab import files
upload = files.upload()

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plot

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.svm import SVC

train_set=pd.read_csv('train.csv')
test_set=pd.read_csv('test.csv')

train_set.head(2)

test_set.head(2)

fig=plot.figure(figsize=(12,4)) #figsize...ウィンドウの大きさ
ax1=fig.add_subplot(121) #ax...グラフ、add_subplot...グラフの場所指定
ax2=fig.add_subplot(122)
#PClass (旅客等級）
PClassPlot=train_set['Survived'].groupby(train_set['Pclass']).mean()
ax1.bar(x=PClassPlot.index,height=PClass.values)
ax1.set_ylabel('Survaival Rate')
ax1.set_xlabel('Gender')
ax1.set_xticks(GenderPlot.index)
ax1_set_yticks(np.arrenge(0,1.1,.1))
ax1.set_title("Class and Survival Rate")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*PClass (旅客等級）* 部分の２行目

```
ax1.bar(x=PClassPlot.index,height=PClass.values)
```

この行を

```
ax1.bar(x=PClassPlot.index,height=PClassPlot.values)
```

に書き換えると直ると思います！

Comment: 解答ありがとうございます！その後、修正したのですが新たな問題が・・・コンパイルしたところ、長ったらしい文とKeyError: 'PClassPlot'というエラーが出てしまったのですがこれに関してはどう対処すればよろしいでしょうか？

Comment: メモ: 上の田中さんによる新たなご質問は、別質問として投稿されました https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/51141/19110