# KeyError: 'PClass'の対処法

Tags: python, python3, 機械学習

[先ほど質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/51130/%e9%9b%91%e8%aa%8c%e3%81%ae%e9%80%9a%e3%82%8a%e3%81%ab%e3%82%b3%e3%83%bc%e3%83%89%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f%e3%81%ae%e3%81%a7%e3%81%99%e3%81%8cnameerror-name-pclass-is-not-defined%e3%81%a8%e5%87%ba%e3%81%a6%e3%81%97%e3%81%be%e3%81%a3%e3%81%9f)させて頂いた者です。回答者様のアドバイスを受けて修正したところ、一部ですがこのようなエラーが出ました。これはどういったエラーなのでしょうか？対処法を教えて頂きたいです。

```
from google.colab import files
upload = files.upload()

from google.colab import files
upload = files.upload()

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plot

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.svm import SVC

train_set=pd.read_csv('train.csv')
test_set=pd.read_csv('test.csv')

train_set.head(2)

test_set.head(2)

fig=plot.figure(figsize=(12,4)) #figsize...ウィンドウの大きさ
ax1=fig.add_subplot(121) #ax...グラフ、add_subplot...グラフの場所指定
ax2=fig.add_subplot(122)
#PClass (旅客等級）
PClassPlot=train_set['Survived'].groupby(train_set['PClass']).mean()
ax1.bar(x=PClassPlot.index,height=PClassPlot.values)
ax1.set_ylabel('Survaival Rate')
ax1.set_xlabel('Gender')
ax1.set_xticks(GenderPlot.index)
ax1_set_yticks(np.arrenge(0,1.1,.1))
ax1.set_title("Class and Survival Rate")
```

↓以下エラー文

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2524             try:
-> 2525                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2526             except KeyError:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'PClass'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kaggle のデータセットを見たのですが、PClassではなくてPclassのようです。スペルを直して実施してみてください。

---

```
test_set.head(2)
```

[image: train_set]

Pclass はこのテーブルの左から３カラム目のことを指しており、

```
train_set['Pclass']
```

pandas のデータフレームではカラム名でその中身のデータだけを指定することができます。

今回の `KeyError` とは、データフレーム内にそのキー（カラム名）が存在しないというエラーです。

参照： https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html#pandas.DataFrame